# How to profile nested loop in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to profile the nested foreach loops in c# code.
How I can measure the total time (sum of each iteration) by the internal (second) loop

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
public class Hello 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        string[] authors = { "Mike Gold", "Don Box", "Sean", "Harp" };       
        Stopwatch stopwatchForDb = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatchForDb.Start();                        
        foreach (var name in authors)
        {          
            string[] authorsTwo = { "Tom", "Jerry","Banny"};
            stopwatchForDb.Restart();      
        
            //want to print total time taken by this loop in complete program 
            foreach (var nameTwo in authorsTwo)
            {   
               Console.WriteLine(name2);              
            }
            
            TimeSpan ts = stopwatchForDb.Elapsed;
            Console.WriteLine(ts);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(name);

    }
 }
```

Comment: Construct it outside both loops. Start it just before the inner loop (this will start it the first time through and Resume it on subsequent calls). Stop it right after the inner loop. Read the total time with one of the ElapsedXxx properties. You're not going to get much useful information, you're doing no useful work in those loops

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
        string[] authorsTwo = { "Tom", "Jerry", "Banny" };
        foreach (var name in authors)
        {
            stopwatchForDb.Restart();
            foreach (var nameTwo in authorsTwo)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(nameTwo);
                Thread.Sleep(1000); //This line is for test output and is not required
            }
            stopwatchForDb.Stop();

            TimeSpan timeTaken = stopwatchForDb.Elapsed;
            Console.WriteLine("total time of loop is:{0}", timeTaken.ToString(@"m\:ss\.fff"));
        }
```